# Keeping on getting run time error 424

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code and it dynamically creates text boxes and labels based on the user input for text box number. But I am getting

> 424 error

I tried to debug using <kbd>F8</kbd>.

I will have a column(dynamically updated) using which the labels have to be created and the count of the column items are the number of textboxes (will replace the input box with count of the column.)

```
Dim number As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i As Long
number = InputBox("enter the number")
Dim txtB1 As Control
For i = 1 To number
    Set txtB1 = Controls.Add(“Forms.TextBox1”)
    With txtB1
    .Name = “txtBox” & i
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 50
    .Left = 70
    .Top = 20 * i * 1
    End With
Next i

Dim lblL1 As Control
For i = 1 To number
    Set lblL1 = Controls.Add(“Forms.Label1”)
    With lblL1
    .Caption = “Label” & i
    .Name = “lbl” & i
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 50
    .Left = 20
    .Top = 20 * i * 1
    End With
Next i

Dim q As Long
For q = 1 To number
    Controls(“lbl” & q) = Cells(1, q)
Next q

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim p As Long
Dim erow As Long
erow = "Sheet3!A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For p = 1 To number

    Cells(erow, p) = Controls(“txtBox” & p).Text

Next p

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

> 424 error is showing problem with this line

```
Set txtB1 = Controls.Add(“Forms.TextBox1”)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must specify `UserForm` you add controls to.

Comment: @AntiDrondert, won't it assume `Me`, because it's in the useform code module?

Comment: `Set txtB1 = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")`

Comment: @CallumDA My bad, it will, I would do that anyway just in case. As for other note, you don't actualy name your controls. `Controls.Add` method consists of 3 parts, first is the object you add controls to, second is the string that identifies control, third is it's name.

Comment: So much questions where one of the issues is typographically double quotes instead of simple double quotes as string quotes in code, which is wrong in most cases. Is this a MAC "feature", or what?

Comment: @AxelRichter, my mac doesn't do that!

Comment: @AxelRichter it worked

Comment: Here's the link that has details about the same code exactly [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyOK2y8x0Cc)

Comment: @YasserKhalil: Ah, [there](https://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/how-to-create-labels-at-runtime/) the typographically double quotes in code are coming from. "Excel VBA Training Online": very nice one ;-).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned already, the correct string to create a textbox on the fly is this:

> Forms.TextBox.1

Notice the additional period `.`. See [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA2/excelvba2lesson21.htm) for reference.

```
Set txtB1 = Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
```

---

To wrap up the other points made in the comments too:

1. You can add an explicit `Me` to make it even more clear where the controls live, i.e. `Me.Controls(...)`. But excluding it will always implicitly link to the correct userform.
2. Just be careful that you use `"` rather than `“`

Comment: it worked but it is no taking the value from worksheet and putting as label name..instead labels are marked as 1,2,3 etc and inside text box i am getting those values that are supposed to be label names

Comment: @qwww: You have replaced the typographically double quotes with simple double qoutes all over the code? In `.Name = “txtBox” & i` the `“txtBox”` is **not** a string literal but a empty variable. It must be `.Name = "txtBox" & i` instead.

Comment: i did it accordinglr...now no labels are shown..but text boxes are created